# How to prove $\int [f(x)+g(x)]dx=\int f(x)dx\,+\int g(x)dx$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are integrable but not continuous?

Tags: calculus, analysis

$$\int [f(x)+g(x)]dx=\int f(x)dx\,+\int g(x)dx$$
How to prove this formula if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are integrable but not continuous?

---

I was reading Mr.Spivak's Calculus, the explanation given for symbol $\int f$ is "the collection of all primitives of $f$". And "primitive" is said as "a function $F$ satisfying $F'=f$". 
The formula is then said as "consequences of theorems about differentiation" in text.
I thought if I try to prove this formula by differentiate both sides, I would need:
1,Both $f$ and $g$ have their primitive.
2,These two primitive have to be differentiable.

Comment: He proved definite integral version of this formula in previous chapter by using upper sum and lower sum which $f$ and $g$ need only be integrable. In this chapter, He introduced this indefinite version first(without proof) and the definite version as a consequence with continuous functions. This is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that indefinite integral is an anti derivative.

In order to prove that$$\int [f(x)+g(x)]dx=\int f(x)dx\,+\int g(x)dx$$

it suffices to show $$d/{dx} (\int f(x)dx\,+\int g(x)dx) =f(x) + g(x)$$

Since differentiation is liner operator we have

$$d/{dx} (\int f(x)dx\,+\int g(x)dx) =$$

$$ d/{dx} (\int f(x)dx) + d/{dx} (\int g(x)dx) = f(x) + g(x)$$

Comment: Should the being differentiated part "$\int f(x)dx$" always exists as a function? My text book says it may not be "found", "found" and "exist" are confusing.

Comment: The functions are integrable  so integrals   exist even if we can not find them.

Comment: Oh, thank you, my confidence is replenished.